# Regular Expression: Start from second one

Tags: regex

I want to find the second `<BR>` tag and to start the search from there. How can i do it using regular expressions?

```
<BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you David. Its because of i woke up early :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend `<BR>[^<]*(?=<BR>)` to your regex, or remove the lookahead part if you want to start *after* the second `<BR>`, such as: `<BR>[^<]*<BR>`.

Find text after the second `<BR>` but before the third: `<BR>[^<]*<BR>([^<]*)<BR>`

This finds "waldo" in `<BR>404<BR>waldo<BR>`.

*Note:* I specifically used the above instead of the non-greedy `.*?` because once the above starts not working for you, you should [stop parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and `.*?` will hide when that happens.  However, the non-greedy quantifier is also not as well-supported, and you can always change to that if you want.

Comment: Note that `<BR>[^<]*<BR>` is not the same as `<BR>.*?<BR>`.

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you but i want to ask 1 more question. This is very good >[^<]* generates this result '>like' . But i want to remove '>' tag from the result. So i just want to have 'like' result. How can i do this?

Comment: @Gumbo, but they have same result.

Comment: uzay95: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: uzay95: No, they are different, and I believe you should use what I answered, for the stated reason.

Comment: @Roger Pate, first i've edited my first comment to express myself better so that i can get "like" word. And could you please tell why they are different?

Comment: uzay95: I still don't understand what you mean.  Could you give example input. actual behavior, and desired behavior? --- They are different when you try to parse HTML, such as this input: `<BR>abc<P>def<BR>ghi</P>jkl<BR>`.

Comment: Look, this my target string: <BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>

and when I write " >[^<]* " the result is equal to : '>like'

As you can see, it includes an undesired character which is " > ". I don't want that. All I am asking is, where am I making a mistake? How can I get my code to just get the word "like" and nothing else.

Comment: To get "like " and nothing else from `<BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>`, use: `<BR>([^<]*)<BR>`.

Comment: To get "Abdurrahman" from `<BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>`, use: `<BR>[^<]*<BR>([^<]*)<BR>`.

Comment: Roger, I really thank you for your patient comments. I've just tried the code you suggested and it seems to return/highlight/include the <BR> and </BR> codes as well. So, I was trying to get rid of ">" character but now I have even more to get rid of. So unfortunately it didn't do what I wanted it to do. I apologize for repeating it again and again but isn't there a way to just highlight the word "like" ?

Comment: There's multiple levels of matching, your program is showing the complete matched text, while you're interested in the first group here (the part between the parentheses); get your program to show you the difference between those.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to this sort of problem is to use a "capturing group". Most regular expression systems allow you to extract not only the entire matching sequence, but also sub-matches within it. This is done by grouping a part of the expression within `(` and `)`. For instance, if I use the following expression (this is in JavaScript; I'm not sure what language you want to be working in, but the basic idea works in most languages):

```
var string = "<BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>";
var match = string.match(/<BR>.*?<BR>([a-zA-Z]*)/);
```

Then I can get either everything that matched using `match[0]`, which is `"<BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman"`, or I can get only the part inside the parentheses using `match[1]`, which gives me `"Abdurrahman"`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for. You might want to clarify your question. This shows you how to find two `<BR>` tags, followed by whatever else you put in the parentheses. For instance, if you are looking for "Father", the search would be `<BR>.*?<BR>.*(Father)`, and the first substring match would refer to where it found `Father`. http://rubular.com/regexes/12836

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using PHP, you can split your string on `<BR>` using explode

```
$str='<BR>like <BR>Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>';
$s = explode("<BR>",$str,3);
$string = end($s);
print $string;
```

output

```
$  php test.php
Abdurrahman<BR><SMALL>Fathers Name</SMALL>
```

you can then use "$string" variable and do whatever you want.

The steps above can be done with other languages as well by using the string splitting methods your prog language has.

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression should math the first two `<br />`s:

`/(\s*<br\s*/?>\s*){2}/i`

so you should either replace them with nothing or use `preg_match` or `RegExp.prototype.match` to extract the arguments.

In JavaScript:

```
var afterReplace = str.replace( /(\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*){2}/i, '' );
```

In PHP

```
$afterReplace = preg_replace( '/(\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*){2}/i', '', $str );
```

I'm only sure it'll work in PHP / JavaScript, but it should work in everything...

Comment: Would you tell me please what is the meaning of this reges '/(\s*<br\s*/?>\s*){2}/i'
 I just want to learn.

Comment: Dan: That won't match given input text of `<br>anything here<br>`, because you don't allow for anything but `\s` between the tags.

Comment: to explain /(\s*<br\s*/?>\s*){2}/i

/   # start regex

(   # start group

\s  # whitespace

*   # any number of previous (inc. zero)

<br # literally this text

/   # literal (should really be //)

?   # zero or one of the previous

>   # literal

\s  # whitespace

*   # zero or more of the previous

)   # end group

{2} # 2 of the group

/   # end regex

i   # match non-case sensitively

(sorry my spacing is lost)